# How to split voltage from a DC power supply?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, split

Given a 12V 4A DC power supply that's connected from a wall outlet to a V59 Universal LCD Controller, can the voltage be split from this power supply to power another device with 5V 1200mA power requirements?  If so, how exactly should the wiring be connected and what other components such as resistors might be needed?

Comment: Yeah, just use a voltage regulator, like the 7805.  You can find more information by Googl'ing it.

Comment: @user95482301, did you notice that the OP may need up to 1.2A at 5V? That is beyond the abilities of a 7805. Also, it is probably not a good application for any linear regulator, because the power dissipation in the regulator will be 1.2A * (12-5V) = 8.4W. A switching regulator would be a better choice.

Comment: @mkeith, "Output Current up to 1.5 A" [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/LM7805.pdf)    I agree that a switching regulator would be better.

Comment: In that case, the best is of course just to buy a "dc dc buck converter" from aliexpress, for $3 incl. shipping.

Comment: Which happen to use, as I understand it, a switching regulator, MC33063AD, like you mentioned.

Comment: Would a LM2956 do the job ( is this a switching regulator or a buck converter ) and, if so, any preference between that and the MC33063AD?  http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Introduction-of-LM2596-Step-Down-Power-Module-/ .. I can get small component boards w/ the LM2956 on it for $2 a piece

Comment: @sean2078, Yes.

Answer (score 6):

You need a 12V to 5V DC-DC step-down converter (also look for: switching regulators). You can find plenty of them in the usual electronics parts vendors.

You could also consider a linear voltage regulator, but that would mean a maximum power dissipation in it of about \$ P_d = (12-5) \cdot 1.2 = 8.4W \$, which will (almost surely) either fry it or drive it into thermal shutdown. Also, it's very inefficient power-wise. Not recommended at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use a high efficiency D.C.-D.C. Converter, these devices are used in hobby remote controls where they are termed a battery eliminator circuit (BEC).  Forget about 7805, too much waste heat.  No other components needed., 12v in, 5v out, very reliaable.

Eg http://www.dx.com/s/Bec?PriceSort=up